# Problemas con las rutas en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un pequeño problema con una de mis rutas...

Tengo mi index el cual me muestra varios productos (9 para ser exactos) al seleccionar uno de mis productos por ende mi ruta cambia con la especificación de mi producto ejemplo: " tienda\donas " en la vista donas tengo un pequeño formulario para ponerse en contacto con migo para dar informes de los productos.

Mi problema surge al momento de llenar mi formulario y mandarlo a mi BD mi ruta cambia a " tienda\gracias-contacto " y me gustaría que dependiendo del producto que elijo la ruta me muestre el mensaje de gracias junto con el producto que seleccione ejemplo "tienda\dona\gracias-contacto" y como todos mis formularios los tengo ligados a un solo controlador al momento de mandarlo siempre me manda a " tienda\gracias-contacto " no se como generar rutas dinámicas o si esa sea la mejor opción o si hay una aun mas sencilla dejo parte de mi código

```
<form action="{{URL::to('save-contact-info')}}" method="POST" id="formulario">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}
                        <div class="title-form">
                            <h3>
                                Informes
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info-form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Nombre:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control input-lg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control input-lg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Teléfono:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="telefono" class="form-control input-lg">
                            </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="producto" value="Donas">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-solicitar" type="submit">
                                    Enviar
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

estas son mis rutas

```
Route::get('donas', 'reposteriaController@donas');

Route::get('pasteles', 'resposteriaController@pasteles');

Route::post('save-contact-info', 'reposteriaController@saveContactInfo');


/*-- Lograr madar el modelo por la url--*/

Route::get('gracias-contacto', 'reposteriaController@gracias');
```

y estos son mis controladores

```
  public function donas(){
            return view('donas');
        }

        public function pasteles(){
            return view('pasteles');
        }

        public function saveContactInfo(Request $request){

            $nombre         = $request->input('nombre');
            $email          = $request->input('email');
            $telefono       = $request->input('telefono');
            $modelo         = $request->input('modelo');

            $nuevo_usuario  = new ContactoReposteria;
                $nuevo_usuario->nombre      = $nombre;
                $nuevo_usuario->email       = $email;
                $nuevo_usuario->telefono    = $telefono;
                $nuevo_usuario->modelo      = $modelo;
            $nuevo_usuario->save();

            $datos          = array(
                'nombre'        => $nombre,
                'email'         => $email,
                'telefono'      => $telefono,
                'modelo'        => $modelo
            );

            Mail::send('front.contacto-reposteria', $datos, function($message) use ($datos){
                $message->to('prueba@gmail.mx')
                ->subject('Contacto Reposteria');
            });

            return redirect('gracias-contacto');
        }

        public function gracias(){

              return view('front.gracias');
        }
    }
```

Como ven tengo aquí dos tipos de productos y me gustaría poderle pasar el nombre de modelo por medio de la ruta para que me identifique que producto es el que se selecciono y dependiendo del producto se muestre en mi url " tienda{modelo-producto}\gracias-contacto "

gracias de antemano por su ayuda y sus sugerencias !!!!

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema?

Comment: has de cuenta todo sirve al 100 me guarda los datos y todo mi problema es en la ruta cuando guardo mi registro de mi formulario y me manda mi mensaje de gracias por contactarnos la ruta que aparece en mi navegador es " tienda\garcias-contacto " y me gustaria que dependiendo del producto que selecciono y lleno el formulario me apareciera " tienda\donas\gracias-contacto " si selecciona mi producto donas ó si selecciona mi otro producto por defecto me mande " tienda\pasteles\gracias-cotacto" es mi problema por que al momento de mandar la info me regresa hasta mi carpeta raíz de tienda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba hacer algo así:

En tus rutas:

```
Route::get('/tienda/{producto}/gracias-contacto', 'reposteriaController@gracias')->name('gracias-contacto');
```

Y en tu controlador cuando redireccionas, hacer esto:

```
return redirect()->route('gracias-contacto', ['producto' => $nombre_producto]);
```

Toma en cuenta que si hay productos con acentos, espacios en blanco o caracteres especiales, tendrías que ponerlos de una manera amigable para la URL. Para eso podrías convertir el nombre del producto en un slug haciendo uso de un helper de laravel:

`$nombre_producto = "pastel de chocolate";`

`str_slug($nombre_producto, '-');`

`// Te imprimiría pastel-de-chocolate`

Comment: listo hice lo que me dijiste y me mando un error de argumento no valido 
InvalidArgumentException in Response.php line 458:
The HTTP status code "1" is not valid.
in Response.php line 458
at Response->setStatusCode(array('modelo' => 'Dona')) in Response.php line 202
at Response->__construct('', array('modelo' => 'Dona'), array()) in RedirectResponse.php line 37
at RedirectResponse->__construct('http://localhost/tienda/gracias-contacto', array('modelo' => 'Dona'), array()) in Redirector.php line 188

Comment: @Bahamut4321 ¿Podrías ponerme como quedó tu código después de agregar lo que te puse?

Comment: @Bahamut4321 Acabo de actualizar la respuesta, le agregue el alias a la ruta, una disculpa, se me fue, la parte de `->name...`

Comment: muchas gracias Aarón Gutiérrez estas en lo correcto lo acabo de poner tal como en tu ejemplo y es como lo necesitaba muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme a solucionar este problema y muchas gracias

Comment: @Bahamut4321 ¡De nada!, como comentario, trata de siempre utilizar el nombre del alias de la ruta, así, si quisieras cambiar la estructura de la URL, por decir, en vez de tienda quieres que se llame "store/{producto}.." sólo tendrías que cambiar el nombre de la URL en el archivo de rutas y no tendrías que actualizar otros archivos. Así que yo evitaría utilizar `redirect('/modelo/{producto}/gracias-contacto',['producto' => $nombre_producto]);`

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, si yo se que el método que utilizaba no era del todo 100% correcto ya llevo 2 meses aprendiendo Laravel y se me complican muchas cosas por el momento, esto lo estaba intentando hacer hacia ya casi dos días y no encontraba la forma, pero con tu ayuda lo solucionaste en menos de 5 minutos y te agradezco por tu tiempo y el buen consejo que me acabas de dar créeme que desde ahora lo pondré en practica gracias Aarón

Comment: @Bahamut4321 No está mal, porque por algo existe, igual si lo llegas a ocupar en algunos escenarios, pero por escalabilidad y mantenimiento si recomendaría utilizar el alias y si jaja con la práctica pronto verás que lo solucionas SÚUUPER rápido, te adjunto mi curso de Laravel... jaja nocierto, pero bueno, suerte y sigue la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6

Answer (score 1):

Ruta

```
Route::get('/modelo/{modelo}/gracias-contacto', 'reposteriaController@gracias');
```

Controlador

```
public function saveContactInfo(Request $request){

    $nombre         = $request->input('nombre');
    $email          = $request->input('email');
    $telefono       = $request->input('telefono');
    $modelo         = $request->input('modelo');

    $nuevo_usuario  = new ContactoReposteria;
        $nuevo_usuario->nombre      = $nombre;
        $nuevo_usuario->email       = $email;
        $nuevo_usuario->telefono    = $telefono;
        $nuevo_usuario->modelo      = $modelo;
    $nuevo_usuario->save();

    $datos          = array(
        'nombre'        => $nombre,
        'email'         => $email,
        'telefono'      => $telefono,
        'modelo'        => $modelo
    );

    Mail::send('front.contacto-reposteria', $datos, function($message) use ($datos){
        $message->to('prueba@gmail.mx')
        ->subject('Contacto Reposteria');
    });

    return redirect('/modelo/{modelo}/gracias-contacto',['modelo' => $modelo]);
```

}

y este es mi controlador donde me direcciona a la vista de gracias

```
public function gracias($modelo){

          return view('front.gracias');
    }
```

y este es el error que me vota

```
InvalidArgumentException in Response.php line 458: The HTTP status code "1" is not valid.

    in Response.php line 458
    at Response->setStatusCode(array('modelo' => 'Dona')) in Response.php line 202
```